# Best way to load xml data into new SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have users info in SQL table with 3 columns. One of the column is in XML datatype which has user information in XML format. The number of columns in the XML data can vary from User to User.For instance, under User 1, i can have 25 fields and then User 2 can have 100 fields . That can change again to 50 for User 3. The fields for each user changes. I need to be able to pull all the fields(columns) under each user and write to a SQL table XYZ.

After writing user A record into SQL table XYZ, User B will have more fields(columns) than A, here i need to ADD these fields(columns) to XYZ table making values as NULL to user A.

Is there an efficient way of achieving this using T-SQL OR SSIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is not the `Data loading mechanism` but the `Data Injection Strategy`

2 strategies I can think of right now:

1. I would suggest you to define an `XSD` for your XML with the worst case (hoping it is definable) scenario and then design your db table around it. As long as the user info conforms to the XSD then you should be fine with your inserts.
2. You create a table like: `Userid | ColumnName | ColumnValue` 
   and then enter the data row-wise , that would give you a lot of flexibility to work around the scenario. You could then always write queries to extract the data in the format you want.